# Tripwire Silent Installation on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install tripwire non-interactively doing the following, but I am still getting window screen for inserting local and site keys. 
The code which I do in bash file is written below.

Can anyone advise a solution for that ?

Thanks

```
TripWireLocalPassword=something
TripWireSitePassword=something

sudo echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select Internet Site" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "postfix postfix/mailname                     string `hostname`"                  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase           password ${TripWireLocalPassword}"  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase-again     password ${TripWireLocalPassword}"  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase            password ${TripWireSitePassword}"   | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase-again      password ${TripWireSitePassword}"   | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/rebuild-config             boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/use-localkey               boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/change-in-default-policy   note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/email-report               note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/broken-passphrase          note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/use-sitekey                boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/installed                  note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase-incorrect  boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/upgrade                    boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/rebuild-policy             boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase-incorrect boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections

sudo apt-get install tripwire
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing but with little success. I did see some older posts that use expect:

http://eigenjoy.com/2009/07/10/automate-installing-tripwire-using-expect/

although I imagine the interface has moved on a fair bit since then. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

With some minor modifications you should be able to install it silently:

```
TripWireLocalPassword=$(tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w30 | head -n1)
TripWireSitePassword=$(tr -cd '[:alnum:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w30 | head -n1)


sudo echo "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type select Internet Site" | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "postfix postfix/mailname                     string `hostname`"                  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase           password ${TripWireLocalPassword}"  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase-again     password ${TripWireLocalPassword}"  | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase            password ${TripWireSitePassword}"   | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase-again      password ${TripWireSitePassword}"   | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/rebuild-config             boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/use-localkey               boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/change-in-default-policy   note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/email-report               note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/broken-passphrase          note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/use-sitekey                boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/installed                  note"                               | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/site-passphrase-incorrect  boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/upgrade                    boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/rebuild-policy             boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo echo "tripwire tripwire/local-passphrase-incorrect boolean true"                       | sudo debconf-set-selections

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install tripwire

echo $TripWireLocalPassword | tripwire --init
```

`DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...` is the magic word.

If you removed previous tripwire installation don't forget to `apt-get purge tripwire` otherwise installation will complain about incorrect local passphrase.

(tested on Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

try something along the lines of

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
sudo apt-get install -q -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" \ 
-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" tripwire
```

From what I have seen there are some packages that ignore the `"export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive"` and instead just open the Whiptail dialog box.

If this is the case you would have to create an expect script.